# Restoring AIX ufsdump on another Unix system

Tags: linux, unix, backup-restoration, aix, ufs

I've previously tried to restore from an AIX `mksysb` image ([question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/697588/restore-of-aix-backup-on-other-unix-system)).

I managed to find another set of nightly AIX backups that look to have been made with `ufsdump`:

```
# mt -t /dev/rmt/1h rew
# dd if=/dev/rmt/1h of=./tapeThu3.out bs=512k
0+116608 records in
0+116608 records out
# file tapeThu3.out
tapeThu3.out:   ufsdump archive file
```

I tried to use `ufsrestore` to view them on Solaris (SPARC):

```
# ufsrestore tvf tapeThu3.out
Verify volume and initialize maps
Media block size is 126
gethead: unknown inode type 11
abort? [yn] y
```

I copied them to Linux, installed `dump` which includes `restore`:

```
[me@CentosXeon TapeRecovery]# restore -i -f tapeThu3.out
gethead: unknown inode type 11
abort? [yn] y
```

I also tried to mount it after installing the UFS filesystem module.  I tried all of the different ufs types and always got:

```
[me@CentosXeon TapeRecovery]#  mount -t ufs -o ufstype=old,loop,ro ./tapeThu3.out ./OpenedImage/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

dmesg shows:

```
ufs_read_super: bad magic number
```

I'm now stumped and still don't have access to an AIX system to try a restore on there.  I know that AIX is big endian (same as Solaris SPARC) and Linux x86 is little endian.  The `restore` command on Linux is meant to cope with both formats though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your AIX system is still working, you can simply mount this UFS dump somewhere at the side (on AIX), and then use rsync tool to replicate files to any other system you want.

Comment: Sorry, no access to an AIX system at all.  We'd hired one (at a cost of eleventy hundred pounds a month, or something equally ridiculous) and it's gone back.  We don't support the client that was on AIX any more.

Comment: Managed to get access to another AIX box so marking this as the accepted answer as it's what I ended up having to do.  For Internet posterity - it looks like there isn't a solution as the AIX file is proprietary.